# Qlik Sense Syntax in Data Loader Script

Tags: qliksense, qlik-expression

How it would be this query in Qlik Sense syntax in data loader script?

```
TABLA_UTIL:
SQL
SELECT "PERIODO", SUM(DEUDAFINAL) as "DEUDAFINAL"
FROM "DL_RG_ANALYTICS"."SH_PROVISION" PRO WHERE ORG='628'
GROUP BY PERIODO

concatenate

SQL
SELECT OL.PERIODO, SUM(ABIERTA/1000000)+ DEUDA/1000000 
FROM "DL_RG_ANALYTICS"."SH_OTRAS_LINEAS" OL LEFT JOIN SH_SALDO_NO_IDEN_RUT PRO ON(OL.PERIODO=PRO.PERIODO)
WHERE ((ol.TIPO_DEUDA='TRASPASO' AND ol.DEFINICION='SALDO' ) 
OR (ol.TIPO_DEUDA='SAE' AND ol.DEFINICION='SALDO' )
OR  (ol.TIPO_DEUDA='REPACTACIONES' AND ol.DEFINICION='SALDO')
OR (ol.TIPO_DEUDA='RENEGOCIADO' AND ol.DEFINICION='SALDO' )
OR (ol.TIPO_DEUDA='AVANCE_EFECTIVO' AND ol.DEFINICION='SALDO' ))
AND PRO.TipoTarjeta='ABIERTA'
GROUP BY OL.PERIODO, PRO.DEUDA
```

Any help is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

that's easy, so cheer up.
If all field names in each table are identical, Qlik Sense will set this to one immediately after the other. To make it unambiguous:

```
concatenate(table_name)
```

is a good idea.

Look at this:

- [qlik script guide concatenate](https://help.qlik.com/de-DE/sense/February2020/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/concatenate.htm)

Here's your example:

```
LIB CONNECT TO 'your_database';

TABLA_UTIL:
  Load *;
  SQL
  SELECT
  "PERIODO",
  SUM(DEUDAFINAL) as "DEUDAFINAL"
  FROM
  "DL_RG_ANALYTICS"."SH_PROVISION" PRO WHERE ORG='628'
  GROUP BY PERIODO;

LIB CONNECT TO 'your_second_database';  // where necessary

concatenate(TABLA_UTIL)  //all field names must be the same

  Load *;
  SQL
  SELECT
   OL.PERIODO as "PERIODO",
   SUM(ABIERTA/1000000)+ DEUDA/1000000 as "DEUDAFINAL"
   FROM
   "DL_RG_ANALYTICS"."SH_OTRAS_LINEAS" OL LEFT JOIN SH_SALDO_NO_IDEN_RUT PRO ON(OL.PERIODO=PRO.PERIODO)
  WHERE ((ol.TIPO_DEUDA='TRASPASO' AND ol.DEFINICION='SALDO' ) 
  OR (ol.TIPO_DEUDA='SAE' AND ol.DEFINICION='SALDO' )
  OR  (ol.TIPO_DEUDA='REPACTACIONES' AND ol.DEFINICION='SALDO')
  OR (ol.TIPO_DEUDA='RENEGOCIADO' AND ol.DEFINICION='SALDO' )
  OR (ol.TIPO_DEUDA='AVANCE_EFECTIVO' AND ol.DEFINICION='SALDO' ))
  AND PRO.TipoTarjeta='ABIERTA'
  GROUP BY OL.PERIODO, PRO.DEUDA;
//done
```

Answer (score 0):

Disagree with previous answer ,
Concatenate is used to concatenate tables with different fields names.
Concatenation of tables with identical set of fields is automatic and can be avoided with NOCONCATENATE keyword (before LOAD)